# sending emails in a loop In PYTHON 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, while-loop, raspberry-pi2

I am currently trying to make a program that send multiple emails to my self in a loop. I have already written 2 patches of code but i can not seem to get them to work. (I am running this on a raspberry pi so exsuse any weird directorys).

This is my first patch of while loop code

```
import os
i = 0
while i < 2:
    os.pause(4)
    os.system("home/Tyler/desktop/test.py")
    i += 1
```

**This opens the email "sending" part /\ .**

**This down here is the "sending" part /**

```
import smtplib

smtpUser = 'smilingexample@gmail.com'
smtpPass = 'password'

toAdd =  'Example@aim.com'
fromAdd = smtpUser

subject = 'yep'
header = 'to: ' + toAdd + '\n' + 'From: ' + fromAdd + '\n' + 'Subject: ' + subject
body = 'hi'

print header + '\n' + body

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()


s.login(smtpUser, smtpPass)
s.sendmail(fromAdd, toAdd, header + '\n\n' + body)

s.quit ()
```

Comment: What is output by the program? Does it complete succssfully?

Comment: no it does not it just underlines all of my varibles in the second line of code

Comment: fourth line, but I'm sure theres more if I were to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
from email import Charset
Charset.add_charset('utf-8', Charset.QP, Charset.QP, 'utf-8')

maillist = []

def send_email(messages_list, smtpUser=None, smtpPass=None, tls=False):
    failed = []
    try:
        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        s.ehlo()
        if tls:
            s.starttls()
            s.ehlo()
        if smtpUser and smtpPass:
            s.login(smtpUser, smtpPass)
    except:
        print "ehlo failed"
        failed = [x[0] for x in messages_list]
    else:
        for to_address,from_address,subject,encoding,mesg in messages_list:
            try:
                if len(mesg) == 2:
                    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
                else:
                    msg = MIMEText(mesg[0],'plain','utf-8')
                msg['Subject'] = "%s" % Header(subject, 'utf-8')
                if len(from_address) == 2:
                    msg['From'] = "\"%s\" <%s>" % (Header(from_address[0], 'utf-8'), from_address[-1])
                else:
                    msg['From'] = from_address[-1]
                if len(to_address) == 2:
                    msg['From'] = "\"%s\" <%s>" % (Header(to_address[0], 'utf-8'), to_address[-1])
                else:
                    msg['To'] = to_address[-1]
                msg.set_charset("utf-8")
                if len(mesg) == 2:
                    part1 = MIMEText(mesg[0], 'plain','utf-8')
                    part2 = MIMEText(mesg[1], 'html','utf-8')
                    msg.attach(part1)
                    msg.attach(part2)
                s.sendmail(from_address[-1], to_address[-1], msg.as_string())
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
                failed.append(to_address[-1])
    try:
        s.quit()
    except:
        pass
    return failed

maillist.append(( ['someone@gmail.com'],["Me","noreply@example.com"],'Subject','utf-8',['text_message','html but you can delete this list element'] ))
for k in send_email(maillist, smtpUser='you@gmail.com', smtpPass='pwd', tls=True):
    print k, 'not delivered'
```

Here's what we use to send alternative Mime messages with alternative body. It is not necessary though so you can send simple text messages as well.

It's prepared to send from localhost but you can easily modify it to use it properly.

Comment: I'm sorry but where do I put the mail list in the main body of python.

Comment: Just copy my full code all together (the top and the bottom with maillist example) into one file and it will work. Don't forget to tweak function to use your login, password and server.

Comment: Obviously I am very new to this judged by my repetition and my python programing ability. My "mother tongue" is JavaScript so this is all new waters

Comment: Also I know we are not supposed to say things like this but Thank you very much this has bothered me for the last couple of days

Comment: I simplified the answer for you, so you can just copy paste and see how it works. You are welcome :)

Comment: Ok i am on that machine right now do i log in with my cridencials where the first two varibles are stmpUser and stmpPass

Comment: You need to modify only the maillist and the smtpUser and smtpPass in the last lines at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106397/discussion-between-tylertotally-and-andrew).